# Resolving the 'Class does not exist' error in Laravel 10

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10, laravel-jetstream

I'm new to Laravel 10, and I recently installed Jetstream. When I run `php artisan route:list` in the console, I get the following error: `Class "verified" does not exist`.

I do have `verified` in my Kernel:

```php
protected $middlewareAliases = [
    ...
    ...
    'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
];
```

in my route in `web.php` i have this

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'verified', 'web'],function(){
  Route::get('/dashboard', [DashboardController::class, 'index'])->name('dashboard');
});
```

in `jetstream.php` there is this `'middleware' => ['auth', 'verified', 'web'],`

and this is the error i see on console

```
   ReflectionException 

  Class "verified" does not exist

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/RouteListCommand.php:225
    221▕             if ($this->isFrameworkController($route)) {
    222▕                 return false;
    223▕             }
    224▕ 
  ➜ 225▕             $path = (new ReflectionClass($route->getControllerClass()))
    226▕                                 ->getFileName();
    227▕         } else {
    228▕             return false;
    229▕         }

      +3 vendor frames 

  4   [internal]:0
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\RouteListCommand::Illuminate\Foundation\Console\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route))
      +16 vendor frames 

  21  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
```

I don't know what I'm missing or how to fix this.

Comment: show a sample of your code where you have the error

Comment: You give no indication of what code is causing this error message, or even a complete error message, so all anybody can do is guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Clear you caches

```php
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan view:clear
```

2. Ensure that your `Verified` middleware is correctly assigned in your routes.

```php
Route::middleware('verified') - > group(function() {
  // Your routes
});
```

3. sometimes the composer autoload files might be out of date. run below command.

```php
composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: tried this, it worked then stopped working a few hours later when i ran `php artisan route:list`. tried to do this again but no luck

Answer (score 0):

`$middlewareAliases` is NOT a class alias. You can do that with `aliases` in the [`app.php`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/7effeb99ec1568f006ed95e60d3e7dfeed1b8160/config/app.php#L185) file

`$middlewareAliases` is used for routes

```php
// allows for this
Route::get('/', SomeController::class)->middleware('verified');

// instead of this
use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class;

Route::get('/', SomeController::class)->middleware(EnsureEmailIsVerified::class);
```

Comment: in `jetsteam.php` there is this `'middleware' => ['auth', 'verified', 'web'],` is this not a middleware alias for routes?